# What are the methods to accurately test the accuracy of a parts of speech tagger?

Tags: algorithms, text-processing

I know that most of the pos tagger algorithms measure their accuracy token wise I.e. whether the token is tagged correctly or not

Some pos taggers provide sentence accuracy too. How is sentence accuracy calculated. Is it like if one token in sentence is wrong then entire sentence is wrong or a sentence is correct if this percent of tags are correct

What are the methods to accurately test the accuracy of a parts of speech tagger?